# Installed latest version of Blender now computer won’t boot up

Tags: installation

I installed the latest version of Blender. When first opened it all I got was a black screen with a cursor. I closed that down then shut my computer down to see if a restart would work, now my computer won’t boot back up. Any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: I wonder how Blender should get your whole computer to not boot anymore... could you provide some details please? Like OS, hardware specs (GPU!), Blender version, etc.?

Comment: Did you install blender to an unusual, system-protected directory?